# bootstrap - internet explorer 8 grid on not working properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

am new to programming am trying to make a website, before that I am trying to understand how it works

I have the code as below.
It works on Chrom & firefox But for IE8 it works like a mobile app.

The grid is not working in horizontal, Its appearing as horizontal in IE8.

Please help me.

& do I need to add  this kind of code for other devices....if so where and how to add this

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">
      <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>
      <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
          <li class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
              <li><a href = "#">Google+</a></li>
              <li><a href = "#">Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "jumbotron">
      <center><h1> Hello, World!</h1>
      <p>As a best practice, we highly recommend using the element whenever possible to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.</p>
      <a class = "btn btn-default">Watch Now!</a>
      <a class = "btn btn-info">Tweet it!</a></center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2">
        <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-3">
        <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "container">
      <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">Site Built By Neil Rowe</p>
      <a href = "http://youtube.com/codersguide" class = "navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/Respond-master/dest/respond.src.js"></script>
  <script src="/Respond-master/src/respond.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```